# In tableview cell, button action not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

Here is the code I've already done:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? { 
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (deleteAction, indexPath) in 
    self.deleteApm(currentIndex: Int) // here getting error
    } 
    return [deleteAction] 
  }   
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
      cell.reSheduleBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myReSheButt(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@IBAction func myReSheButt(_ sender: UIButton) {
    reSheduleApm()
}

func reSheduleApm(){
    let jsonDict = self.ArrayList[indexPath.row] as? [String:Any]
    let appId:Int  = jsonDict?["appId"] as! Int
    let appId2 : Int = jsonDict?["appId"] as! Int
    var appString = String(appId2)
    let schedDay = jsonDict?["sDate"] as! String
    let params: [String : String] = ["day":schedDay,"appId":appString]

    let url = APIdata.URL_APP_RESHED

    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            for (key, value) in params
            {
                multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
            }
    },
        to: url,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response.value as Any)
                //                    self.ArrayList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                //                    self.tblView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
        case .failure(_):
            break
            }
    })
}
```

In tableview cell, button action not working even if the function writes outside.
 Inside `editActionsForRowAt` in `UITableview` the function cannot call inside the `myReSheButt` button Action.

And the function cannot call inside the editActionsForRowAt Also getting error

How to solve this?

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Currently, it won't compile because you have many nested functions. You are missing at least one closing curly brace.

Comment: selectors can call functions preceded by @ objc , unless you have a good reason for using a @ IBAction you probably shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass your tag in cell for row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
 cell.reSheduleBtn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.reSheduleBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myReSheButt(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

return cell
}
```

and handle the action as

```
@objc func myReSheButt(_ sender: UIButton) {
reSheduleApm(currentIndex: sender.tag)
}
```

ans pass your currentIndex to your reSheduleApm

```
func reSheduleApm(currentIndex: Int){
    let jsonDict = self.ArrayList[currentIndex] as? [String:Any]
    let appId:Int  = jsonDict?["appId"] as! Int
    let appId2 : Int = jsonDict?["appId"] as! Int
    var appString = String(appId2)
    let schedDay = jsonDict?["sDate"] as! String
    let params: [String : String] = ["day":schedDay,"appId":appString]

    let url = APIdata.URL_APP_RESHED

    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            for (key, value) in params
            {
                multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
            }
    },
        to: url,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response.value as Any)
                //                    self.ArrayList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                //                    self.tblView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                //
            }
        case .failure(_):
            break
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: using "currentIndex" the selected row button not calling  another row  is calling...

Comment: yes, iam not added this line "cell.reSheduleBtn.tag = indexPath.row" so i get the problem, this answer is correct, who downvote this?, what is the reason?

Comment: @SruthiCSankar - simple , inthis line use `self.deleteApm(currentIndex: indexPath.row)` // here getting error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191717/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-sruthi-c-sankar).